# How to calculate 95% Confidence intervals for categorical data (Daily, Occasionally, Never)

Tags: sas, confidence-interval

I asked a random selection of people the following question "How often do you smoke?". The answer categories were as follows: 1. Daily 2. Occasionally or 3. Never .  I have details about the respondents such as age and gender.

The results are as follows:

10% of respondents smoke daily. 
5% smoke occasionally.
85% Never smoke.

My question is:

Is it possible to calculate confidence intervals around this categorical data? i.e. 10% of respondents smoke daily, lower CI= 8% upper Ci=12%.

I am using R, SAS and python to investigate this.

I have sourced this SAS code:

```
     proc freq data=smoking_data;
     tables smoke / binomial(level='1'); /*Daily*/

     tables smoke / binomial(level='2'); /*Occasionally*/

     tables smoke / binomial(level='3'); /*Never*/

    run;
```

This appears to work but I am unsure if Binomial is correct to use with categorical data.

Thank you for any help in advance

Answer (score 0):

I would call this an ordinal variable, but what you're doing looks fine.  There's a better explanation than I could write here:

[https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/224243/how-to-calculate-confidence-intervals-for-a-population-proportion-ordinal-varia][1]